# motherboard takes too long to finish POST (z77x ud5h)

Tags: motherboard, post

when I press the power button, it takes about 7 seconds to beep and show the gigabyte logo on screen. I have one hdd connected to sata3_0 port, two sticks of ram placed on the recommended slots by the manual and a sapphire 5770. removing the vga or changing the hdd with another made no difference.

also, while waiting the debug 7-segments show '15' which is "Pre-memory North-Bridge initialization is started." maybe it's a chipset thing?

is it normal to take **this** long? my older p45 took way less...
(i'm trying to reach out to someone with the same motherboard to tell me his/her experience)

Comment: I'm not sure if your bios has fdd, but if so, try to disable it. Had similar issue, with long bios post times

Comment: the motherboard doesn't even have the fdd port :-P I'll check for "legacy" options though